# MIT APP Inventor 2 text box property as integer

Tags: app-inventor

I needs a text box which only allow integers bigger than "0". My blocks can make it to only accept positive numbers, but I have no idea how to make it an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the below. Tried to judge if it's a number first and then "round" it to be integer and then "absolute" it to be positive number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you only can set the textbox to *numbers only* true or false...
but you could try the [textbox extension](https://puravidaapps.com/textbox.php) and its **AfterTextChanged** event to check, if a number < 0 was entered...

[image]

Comment: I found another way which is using " ROUND" along with "ABS" to make it integer.

Comment: you might want to replace your comment as answer and provide a screenshot of your relevant blocks as solution